# retrieving xml data

Tags: php, html, xml

In `stores.htm`, I have to input two values: one for street address (streetno and street name) and the other for suburb. On the basis of providing inputs, it retrieves data from the `stores.xml` file.

The problem is that the street address and suburb are both stored in the `<address>` element of the `stores.xml` file, not separately. I tried a lot but I'm not finding a solution of how to match inputs with the xml file data.

I am stuck in the `if (condition)`which is in php file

#### stores.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<stores>
<store>
<name>galaxy</name>
<address>50 Callander Road,Noble park</address>
</store>
<store>
<name>Remica</name>
<address>10 Challander Road,Noble park</address>
</store>
<store>
<name>Home</name>
<address>10/10 Callan Road,Richmond</address>
</store>
</stores>
```

#### stores.htm

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" > 
<head> 
<title>Search</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="search.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<form> 
Enter Street Address: <input type="text" name="street" /> 
Enter Suburb        : <input type="text" name="suburb" />
<input name="submit" type = "button" onClick = "getData('search.php','info', street.value, suburb.value)" value = "Search"  /> 
</form>

<div id="info" /> 

</body> 
</html>
```

#### search.php

```
         $street= $_POST["str"];
         $suburb= $_POST["sub"];

         $xmlFile = "stores.xml";
         $doc= DOMDocument::load($xmlFile);
         $store = $doc->getElementsByTagName("store"); 
         echo "<table border=1><tr><th>Name</th></tr>";   
          foreach($store as $node) 
         {   
        $name = $node->getElementsByTagName("name");
        $name = $name->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $address = $node->getElementsByTagName("address");
        $address = $address->item(0)->nodeValue;     

        if( /* what goes here? */ )  {
            echo"<tr><td>name</td></tr>";   
        }

      echo "</table>";
```

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to do with the address? Split it on the comma?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's [explode function](http://php.net/explode) to separate the street address from the suburb.

```
// split the address into two parts, street and suburb, using delimiter ','
$address_split = explode(',', $address);
$address_street = $address_split[0];
$address_suburb = $address_split[1];

if ($address_street == $street && $address_suburb == $suburb) {
    // code here
}
```

Comment: ...or strtok with ','. You may also want to use strtolower to put both query and data in lower case to ease pattern matching and trim to remove any white space at ends of these strings.